# HTML/CSS - Limiting span lengths and lining up multiple spans

Tags: html, css

I have a few spans in a fixed width container.

One of the spans is longer than the others and changes in size at different times. I'm trying to limit this span to a maximum width so that the 3 spans fit on one line.

What I have so far works, but the problem is the span that is limited in length is slightly offset and the spans don't line up perfectly. What should I do to make all 3 spans fit on one line and align with each other so they look normal?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/579cwmbv/

Code:

```
.container {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.spanContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}

.long {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 156px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.short {
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class='container'>
<div class='spanContainer'>
<span class='short'>Results near </span>
<span class='long'>"Seattle, WA, 98005, United States"</span>
<span class='short'>Change</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox?

Comment: Not familiar with it... How would that work?

Comment: Oh... you change "display: inline-block" of "container" to "display: flex" and it immediately is fixed. If you answer the question I'll give you credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flex

```
.spanContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you format the spans in the same way as each other they line up:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.spanContainer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.long,
.short {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 156px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='spanContainer'>
    <span class='short'>Results near </span>
    <span class='long'>"Seattle, WA, 98005, United States"</span>
    <span class='short'>Change</span>
  </div>
</div>
```